# Blank page when using pdfpages package

Tags: pdfpages, blank-page

I have a file `fooo.pdf` with dimension `210mm x 70mm` and 6 pages (simple grey background).

I'm using `pdfpages` to include the pages inside an `A4` page.

So the ideal number is 4 pages per page. But the problem is that the output has a blank page at the beginning.

Why? How to fix it?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}%
\noindent\includepdf[nup=1x4,pages=-]{fooo.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What happens without `\noindent`? If the problem persists, you can always discard it internally using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi)...

Comment: I can not believe!! So simple! It works. Thanks @Werner.

Comment: It token me 5 minutes to prepare the counter example and just 5 seconds to solve.

Comment: @Werner, how can I know that `\parindent` is not being used in front of included pdf page? Just setting the left margin to zero is not enough to remove the space!

Comment: The placement of pages using `\includepdf` always inserts it on a blank page and doesn't take any of the page margins into account (as far as I know). You can change things like the `offset` or `delta`s. The only reason why page layout would be considered is if you use `\includegraphics[page=..]{<pdf>}`.

Comment: @Werner, so the `\noindent` had started a new page before the one created by the `pdfpages`. I got! Thanks.

Comment: @Werner If I have the same problem without using the `\indntfirst` how should I use the `atbegshi` package in this case? I'm reviewing the package documentation, but I'm not clear on how the code would be needed to prevent `pdfpages` from inserting that blank page.

Comment: @Aradnix: Perhaps look at `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`... alternatively, provide a minimal document that I can look at (post it on [Pastebin](//pastebin.com), say).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) inserts `\newpage` before inserting any content, as well as after the content has been inserted. As such, anything set before the issue of the `\newpage` would cause a complete page break. The primitive `\noindent` here switches to horizontal mode and therefore initiates a paragraph, even though nothing is set. As such, the `\newpage` leaves a visible blank page. Remove it to avoid the first blank page.

You could also consider using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) to process pages before they're shipped out, and perhaps conditionally (`\AtBeginShipoutFirst`) discard them using `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`.